# How can I re-upload a CSV after processing it with fast-csv to S3 with streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fast-csv

I'm attempting to download csv files from S3, perform some transforms on the data (in this example, hardcoding an ID), and then reupload it back to S3 as a 'processed' version of the file whilst using streams to avoid running out of memory. [Fast-csv](https://c2fo.github.io/fast-csv/) looked to be a good library to do this with.

Consider the following code:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-west-2' });
const getFileFromS3 = async () => {
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Key: 'originaldata.csv',
  });
  const getFile = await s3Client.send(command);
  const stream = await getFile.Body;
  return stream;
};

const csvParser = csv
  .parse({ headers: true })
  .transform((data) => ({
    ...data,
    id: 'TEST',
  }))
  .on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
  .on('data', (row) => console.log(row))
  .on('end', (rowCount: number) => console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`));

  const fileStream = await getFileFromS3();
  const transformationStream = new PassThrough();
  
  fileStream.pipe(csvParser).pipe(transformationStream);

  const upload = new Upload({
    client: s3Client,
    params: {
      Bucket: 'mybucket',
      Key: 'processeddata.csv',
      Body: transformationStream,
    },
  });
  await upload.done();
```

But when doing this, I get the following error:

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object`

It would seem another person has encountered this in the [fast-csv repo](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/issues/783), but the solution was never given.

Comment: If language is not a contraint, I will prefer to use python and then use the aws pandas api library much easy to do these things and reupload. https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/011%20-%20CSV%20Datasets.html